# URL Rewriting redirecting to same page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have below redirect rules setup in web.cinfig using URLRewrite module.

See the Rule1 and Rule2 got the same page name (Contact.aspx), but the pages are in different folder and should redirect to different location. Instead everything going to target of the 'Rule1'.
Anyone take a look it and help me to fix this?

```
<rule name="Rule1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Service/Contact.aspx/?" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.samplesite.com/me-two/help/contact" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule2" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Commercial/Service/Contact.aspx/?" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.samplesite.com/commercial/help/contact" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule3" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Service/Contact.aspx/?" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.otherwebsite.com/commercial/help/contact" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cap symbol at the beginning of the url

```
<match url="^Service/Contact.aspx/?" />
```